# Why is "net = net.cuda()" or "net = net.to(device)" taking so long?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm working in a small deep learning model with pytorch, but it takes around 30 minutes just to get past this line of code:

```
net = net.to(device) // or net = net.cuda()
```

As far as I know, this should be done in very little time, so I don't get why it's taking so long.

I'm using a NVIDIA 4GB GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU.

Comment: it should not be that long. so something is wrong, maybe array is larger then cuda memory but in this case there must be also the different reaction. Something is wrong in the system like Cuda installation, dkn. i never got this

Comment: You may have a mismatch between your CUDA version and your GPU, which might be resulting in JIT recompilation of libraries.  This is known to take a long time.  Since you've not provided any of that information, I have no idea if this is a possibility.

Comment: If your CUDA version in use is less than 11.1, the explanation for the long delay is very likely in JIT compilation of libraries to meet the cc8.6 GPU you are using.  In that case, the recommended fix is to use a newer CUDA version.  Yes, this certainly has implications for your pytorch build, how you installed it, and etc.

Comment: @RobertCrovella you should probably copy that to an answer, since it seems like the likely answer (even if it isn't for OP, because it is still likely the answer for others)